# Image is shown in half width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm completing a FrontEnd project, and I'm using Bootstrap 3 for the grid system.

Now, I'm also using art direction using the picture element, but I have a problem with this images because, every time I added this source element: `<source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="images/web-development.jpg 1x, images/web-development_2x.jpg 2x">`, the picture is displayed 50% of the size of the picture. Does anyone know why might this happen?

```
<section class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<picture>
<source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="images/web-development.jpg 1x, images/web-development_2x.jpg 2x">
<source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="images/web-development-small_1x.jpg 1x, images/web-development-small_2x.jpg 2x">
<img src="images/web-development.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Common desktop of a developer">
</picture>
</div>
</section>
```

I've also tried like this and the same result happens

```
<section class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<picture>
<source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="images/web-development-small_1x.jpg 1x, images/web-development-small_2x.jpg 2x">
<img src="images/web-development.jpg" srcset="images/web-development.jpg 1x, images/web-development_2x.jpg 2x" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Common desktop of a developer">
</picture>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you show us your CSS?

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm using Bootstrap which class is .img-responsive { max-width: 100%; height: auto} Do you think it might be the browser? but I've tested it in Safari and Chrome and the same problem. I go to DevTool and I checked in the console $0.NaturalWidth and it tells me that is 960px which is not, because is 1920px, I go to the image and get the info and is 1920px

Answer (score 2):

I finally found an answer.

I created my own class in my style.css, and instead of adding max-width: 100%; I added it width: 100%.

And the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

**Have a read on srcset:**
https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/

The reason you are getting 50% smaller is normal, the higher the pixel ratio / density 2x, 3x, 4x and so on, the smaller the image will display because monitor resolution is fix.

When you apply image with 1x solution will be the default dimension (e.g. 100px by 100px), when the resolution is doubled, in this case 2x you will need 200px by 200px to maintain the same size.

Comment: Yes, but when I remove the srcset from the img tag or the source tag (child of the picture) and the src="images/web-development_2x.jpg" the image is displayed at its normal size which is 1920. Thanks for you answer